# Structuring my dataset in a way similar to CIFAR-10

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have been looking around for a clear answer to my question, but still couldn't find such answer, although I found kind of similar questions in Stackoverflow.

I have a dataset that I would like to structure in a same way as in [CIFAR-10](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html), but not sure how to do that.

What should I do in order to structure my dataset in a same way as CIFAR-10?

Thanks.